# 2 buttons, 1 that starts an MP3 file and 1 that stops

Tags: java, android, button, mp3

I know how to start the music file, but I don't know how to stop it. Here's my main activity:

```
public void button1 (View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your media player is within the scope of the method. Declare it in your class.

```
Class MediaDemo{

MediaPlayer mp=null;
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);

public void button1 (View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
} 


public void button2 (View v){

   // your code goes here
    mp.stop();
}
```

Comment: I didn't make it work. I have made a new project to show better what i have done. What am i doing wrong?? http://gyazo.com/9c1f1fd10aa3ad661c8172e85de7d6f4

Answer (score 0):

Declare the mp as global in that class and do mp.stop();

Comment: I am i newbee.. How do i "declare the mp as global"? I'd appreciate an answer :)

Comment: My bad :) I wrote this on my phone planning to edit it in 5 mins or so with the actual code. No need now I guess, vembutech gave u the answer. :)

Comment: I didn't make it work. I have made a new project to show better what i have done. What am i doing wrong?? http://gyazo.com/9c1f1fd10aa3ad661c8172e85de7d6f4

Comment: Nvm vembutech helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your xml file with two buttons and set the button ID as ,playButton and stopButton

now use the below code..

```
public class MediaPlayerExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button playButton,stopButton;
    MediaPlayer mp=null;
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_xml_file);
        playButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ShowDialog);
        stopButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ShowToast);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.playButton: // your button should have this id in xml file
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start();
            break;
        case R.id.stopButton: //your button should have this id in xml file
            mp.stop();
            break;
        }

    }
```